# Multiple t-test on independent group with a large dataframe

Tags: r, t-test, hypothesis-test

I've seen many similar posts but the vast majority of them are at least 3 years old and I'm not really sure they apply to my situations, so here we go.

A colleague asked for my help on a multiple t-test on her project.

Basically she has 20 observation x 30 variable dataframe that looks like this:
| Group | Lipid 1 | Lipid 2 | ... | Lipid 28|

| -------- | -------------- |

| A   |
|B   |
|  |
|B   |

What we want to do is a group comparison of each lipide (meaning a t-test for Lipide 1 between group A and B, then a t-test for Lipide 2 and so on).

We do not want to compare Lipids between them.

And of course, we'd like to not have to copy/paste the same 3 lines of code, especially since we've got 2 other dataframe with the same variable but different conditions.

I've tried one solution I saw in here but it gives me an error I'm not sure to understand:

```
sapply(foetal[,2:20], function(i) t.test(i ~ foetal$ID)) 
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning messages: 1: In mean.default(x) : l'argument n'est ni numérique, ni logique : renvoi de NA 2: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion 3: In mean.default(y) : l'argument n'est ni numérique, ni logique : renvoi de NA 4: In var(y) : Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Another solution I saw would by to use the gather function to get one column with the Lipids, one column for the value of each Lipids, then create a list column, spread the dataframe and mutate a new-column containing the p-value of the t-test.

```
tips %>% 
  select(tip, total_bill, sex) %>% 
  gather(key = variable, value = value, -sex) %>% 
  group_by(sex, variable) %>% 
  summarise(value = list(value)) %>% 
  spread(sex, value) %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(p_value = t.test(unlist(Female), unlist(Male))$p.value,
         t_value = t.test(unlist(Female), unlist(Male))$statistic)
```

(https://sebastiansauer.github.io/multiple-t-tests-with-dplyr/)

I'm honestly not sure what to do. Does anyone have tips or anything?

Here's the dput() for the data.... Not really sure why it's necessary though...

```
dput(dummy)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    Lipid.1 = c(0.737, 0.419, 0.468, 0.805, 1.036, 0.825, 0.286, 
    1.166, 0.898, 0.504, 1.433, 0.41, 0.325, 0.866, 0.337, 0.876, 
    0.636, 0.953, 0.481, 0.602), Lipid.2 = c(0.001, 0.017, 0.013, 
    0.025, 0.018, 0.003, 0.007, NA, 0.01, 0.002, 0.01, 0.022, 
    0.005, NA, 0.018, NA, 0.015, 0.016, NA, 0.01), Lipid.3 = c(0.035, 
    0.018, 0.036, 0.024, 0.023, 0.027, 0.036, 0.037, 0.013, 0.037, 
    0.03, 0.04, 0.038, 0.033, 0.016, 0.034, 0.029, 0.033, 0.018, 
    0.029), Lipid.4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Lipid.5 = c(0.09, 
    0.099, 0.12, 0.058, 0.136, 0.103, 0.153, 0.148, 0.047, 0.085, 
    0.098, 0.133, 0.099, 0.121, 0.084, 0.065, 0.11, 0.088, 0.065, 
    0.043), Lipid.6 = c(0.39, 0.555, 0.568, 0.6, 0.626, 0.378, 
    0.657, 0.57, 0.271, 0.41, 0.474, 0.617, 0.491, 0.738, 0.459, 
    0.365, 0.499, 0.388, 0.271, 0.275), Lipid.7 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Lipid.8 = c(0.186, 0.197, 0.191, 0.125, 0.209, 
    0.107, 0.174, 0.143, 0.055, 0.134, 0.148, 0.193, 0.184, 0.213, 
    0.134, 0.085, 0.165, 0.215, 0.163, 0.061), Lipid.9 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "0,007"), Lipid.10 = c("0,242", "0,254", "0,134", 
    "0,226", "0,243", "0,122", "0,082", "0,119", "0,098", "0,093", 
    "0,27", "0,284", "0,258", "0,236", "0,173", "0,106", "0,138", 
    "0,066", "0,072", "0,081"), Lipid.11 = c("0,053", "0,114", 
    "0,038", "0,094", "0,073", "0,067", "0,028", "0,022", "0,021", 
    "0,05", "0,085", "0,102", "0,122", "0,096", "0,027", "0,03", 
    NA, "0,078", "0,066", NA), Lipid.12 = c(0.223, 0.261, 0.258, 
    0.212, 0.168, 0.101, 0.191, 0.09, 0.195, 0.082, 0.155, 0.2, 
    0.167, 0.231, 0.145, 0.089, 0.239, 0.141, 0.106, 0.124), 
    Lipid.13 = c(0.737, 0.763, 0.707, 0.587, 0.545, 0.317, 0.74, 
    0.602, 0.481, 0.531, 0.632, 0.448, 0.62, 0.766, 0.397, 0.623, 
    0.997, 0.578, 0.418, 0.412), Lipid.14 = c(0.683, 0.666, 0.507, 
    0.366, 0.443, 0.266, 0.493, 0.345, 0.368, 0.355, 0.432, 0.411, 
    0.491, 0.565, 0.357, 0.285, 0.604, 0.426, 0.538, 0.295), 
    Lipid.15 = c(0.911, 1.017, 0.503, 0.76, 0.741, 0.486, 0.648, 
    0.581, 0.955, 0.515, 0.932, 0.707, 0.626, 0.928, 0.836, 0.537, 
    0.654, 0.351, 0.498, 0.529), Lipid.16 = c(0.148, 0.116, 0.069, 
    0.104, 0.091, 0.064, 0.093, 0.123, 0.11, 0.097, 0.283, 0.076, 
    0.095, 0.194, 0.06, 0.061, 0.086, 0.051, 0.064, 0.059), Lipid.17 = c("0,155", 
    "0,274", "0,149", "0,127", "0,174", "nd", "0,109", "0,134", 
    "0,1", "0,09", "0,25", "0,112", "0,088", "0,243", "0,092", 
    "0,073", "0,153", "0,12", "0,14", "0,06"), Lipid.18 = c(3.143, 
    3.441, 4.359, 1.945, 2.573, 2.267, 3.585, 3.405, 2.296, 1.998, 
    3.468, 2.98, 3.626, 3.635, 3.236, 2.092, 2.586, 2.08, 1.718, 
    1.736), Lipid.19 = c(37.993, 36.148, 40.244, 30.395, 37.339, 
    35.742, 47.316, 47.555, 34.351, 32.377, 38.694, 39.413, 36.114, 
    41.235, 32.779, 32.222, 36.418, 36.918, 33.334, 31.421), 
    Lipid.20 = c(6.613, 5.913, 9.662, 3.789, 7.485, 6.297, 8.254, 
    8.07, 4.905, 5.686, 7.742, 7.533, 6.875, 7.908, 7.022, 5.446, 
    6.1, 6.782, 6.062, 6.089), Lipid.21 = c(7.235, 6.759, 8.331, 
    4.931, 6.558, 4.186, 5.99, 5.629, 3.066, 3.439, 7.102, 7.655, 
    6.606, 7.858, 5.804, 3.135, 3.218, 3.639, 2.975, 3.13), Lipid.22 = c(6.453, 
    6.664, 9.048, 4.341, 8.03, 7.599, 10.24, 10.954, 5.873, 6.687, 
    8.005, 8.908, 6.708, 8.06, 5.931, 6.083, 5.734, 5.587, 5.388, 
    6.088), Lipid.23 = c(4.943, 3.164, 5.153, 2.51, 4.071, 5.255, 
    7.636, 8.376, 4.726, 5.56, 4.762, 5.044, 4.549, 4.875, 4.57, 
    5.147, 4.396, 4.031, 3.556, 4.38), Lipid.24 = c(3.973, 4.279, 
    5.928, 3.066, 4.95, 4.667, 7.949, 7.268, 4.948, 3.72, 5.137, 
    5.539, 4.006, 5.276, 3.909, 4.163, 4.954, 5.02, 3.961, 4.201
    ), Lipid.25 = c(7.638, 5.224, 8.417, 3.902, 7.267, 6.007, 
    8.256, 7.457, 4.801, 4.86, 7.581, 8.173, 7.57, 8.591, 7.482, 
    5.091, 5.651, 6.577, 5.415, 5.76), Lipid.26 = c(10.225, 8.293, 
    13.188, 5.607, 10.993, 4.491, 5.767, 5.011, 3.589, 3.145, 
    11.471, 12.183, 9.686, 12.562, 9.697, 3.34, 4.186, 4.485, 
    3.23, 4.229), Lipid.27 = c(5.848, 4.856, 6.503, 3.534, 5.358, 
    8.933, 14.034, 12.806, 7.781, 8.094, 6.765, 6.867, 5.539, 
    7.772, 5.883, 7.832, 8.607, 7.586, 6.628, 7.563), Lipid.28 = c(32.941, 
    30.579, 31.358, 15.861, 30.353, 25.222, 35.662, 34.035, 20.338, 
    24.682, 30.698, 34.024, 31.608, 37.539, 24.901, 20.131, 23.126, 
    30.803, 25.639, 18.935)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to have the full t-test output, you could just loop over the columns:

If we start with your df:

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    Lipid.1 = c(0.737, 0.419, 0.468, 0.805, 1.036, 0.825, 0.286, 
    1.166, 0.898, 0.504, 1.433, 0.41, 0.325, 0.866, 0.337, 0.876, 
    0.636, 0.953, 0.481, 0.602), Lipid.2 = c(0.001, 0.017, 0.013, 
    0.025, 0.018, 0.003, 0.007, NA, 0.01, 0.002, 0.01, 0.022, 
    0.005, NA, 0.018, NA, 0.015, 0.016, NA, 0.01), Lipid.3 = c(0.035, 
    0.018, 0.036, 0.024, 0.023, 0.027, 0.036, 0.037, 0.013, 0.037, 
    0.03, 0.04, 0.038, 0.033, 0.016, 0.034, 0.029, 0.033, 0.018, 
    0.029), Lipid.4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Lipid.5 = c(0.09, 
    0.099, 0.12, 0.058, 0.136, 0.103, 0.153, 0.148, 0.047, 0.085, 
    0.098, 0.133, 0.099, 0.121, 0.084, 0.065, 0.11, 0.088, 0.065, 
    0.043), Lipid.6 = c(0.39, 0.555, 0.568, 0.6, 0.626, 0.378, 
    0.657, 0.57, 0.271, 0.41, 0.474, 0.617, 0.491, 0.738, 0.459, 
    0.365, 0.499, 0.388, 0.271, 0.275), Lipid.7 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Lipid.8 = c(0.186, 0.197, 0.191, 0.125, 0.209, 
    0.107, 0.174, 0.143, 0.055, 0.134, 0.148, 0.193, 0.184, 0.213, 
    0.134, 0.085, 0.165, 0.215, 0.163, 0.061), Lipid.9 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "0,007"), Lipid.10 = c("0,242", "0,254", "0,134", 
    "0,226", "0,243", "0,122", "0,082", "0,119", "0,098", "0,093", 
    "0,27", "0,284", "0,258", "0,236", "0,173", "0,106", "0,138", 
    "0,066", "0,072", "0,081"), Lipid.11 = c("0,053", "0,114", 
    "0,038", "0,094", "0,073", "0,067", "0,028", "0,022", "0,021", 
    "0,05", "0,085", "0,102", "0,122", "0,096", "0,027", "0,03", 
    NA, "0,078", "0,066", NA), Lipid.12 = c(0.223, 0.261, 0.258, 
    0.212, 0.168, 0.101, 0.191, 0.09, 0.195, 0.082, 0.155, 0.2, 
    0.167, 0.231, 0.145, 0.089, 0.239, 0.141, 0.106, 0.124), 
    Lipid.13 = c(0.737, 0.763, 0.707, 0.587, 0.545, 0.317, 0.74, 
    0.602, 0.481, 0.531, 0.632, 0.448, 0.62, 0.766, 0.397, 0.623, 
    0.997, 0.578, 0.418, 0.412), Lipid.14 = c(0.683, 0.666, 0.507, 
    0.366, 0.443, 0.266, 0.493, 0.345, 0.368, 0.355, 0.432, 0.411, 
    0.491, 0.565, 0.357, 0.285, 0.604, 0.426, 0.538, 0.295), 
    Lipid.15 = c(0.911, 1.017, 0.503, 0.76, 0.741, 0.486, 0.648, 
    0.581, 0.955, 0.515, 0.932, 0.707, 0.626, 0.928, 0.836, 0.537, 
    0.654, 0.351, 0.498, 0.529), Lipid.16 = c(0.148, 0.116, 0.069, 
    0.104, 0.091, 0.064, 0.093, 0.123, 0.11, 0.097, 0.283, 0.076, 
    0.095, 0.194, 0.06, 0.061, 0.086, 0.051, 0.064, 0.059), Lipid.17 = c("0,155", 
    "0,274", "0,149", "0,127", "0,174", "nd", "0,109", "0,134", 
    "0,1", "0,09", "0,25", "0,112", "0,088", "0,243", "0,092", 
    "0,073", "0,153", "0,12", "0,14", "0,06"), Lipid.18 = c(3.143, 
    3.441, 4.359, 1.945, 2.573, 2.267, 3.585, 3.405, 2.296, 1.998, 
    3.468, 2.98, 3.626, 3.635, 3.236, 2.092, 2.586, 2.08, 1.718, 
    1.736), Lipid.19 = c(37.993, 36.148, 40.244, 30.395, 37.339, 
    35.742, 47.316, 47.555, 34.351, 32.377, 38.694, 39.413, 36.114, 
    41.235, 32.779, 32.222, 36.418, 36.918, 33.334, 31.421), 
    Lipid.20 = c(6.613, 5.913, 9.662, 3.789, 7.485, 6.297, 8.254, 
    8.07, 4.905, 5.686, 7.742, 7.533, 6.875, 7.908, 7.022, 5.446, 
    6.1, 6.782, 6.062, 6.089), Lipid.21 = c(7.235, 6.759, 8.331, 
    4.931, 6.558, 4.186, 5.99, 5.629, 3.066, 3.439, 7.102, 7.655, 
    6.606, 7.858, 5.804, 3.135, 3.218, 3.639, 2.975, 3.13), Lipid.22 = c(6.453, 
    6.664, 9.048, 4.341, 8.03, 7.599, 10.24, 10.954, 5.873, 6.687, 
    8.005, 8.908, 6.708, 8.06, 5.931, 6.083, 5.734, 5.587, 5.388, 
    6.088), Lipid.23 = c(4.943, 3.164, 5.153, 2.51, 4.071, 5.255, 
    7.636, 8.376, 4.726, 5.56, 4.762, 5.044, 4.549, 4.875, 4.57, 
    5.147, 4.396, 4.031, 3.556, 4.38), Lipid.24 = c(3.973, 4.279, 
    5.928, 3.066, 4.95, 4.667, 7.949, 7.268, 4.948, 3.72, 5.137, 
    5.539, 4.006, 5.276, 3.909, 4.163, 4.954, 5.02, 3.961, 4.201
    ), Lipid.25 = c(7.638, 5.224, 8.417, 3.902, 7.267, 6.007, 
    8.256, 7.457, 4.801, 4.86, 7.581, 8.173, 7.57, 8.591, 7.482, 
    5.091, 5.651, 6.577, 5.415, 5.76), Lipid.26 = c(10.225, 8.293, 
    13.188, 5.607, 10.993, 4.491, 5.767, 5.011, 3.589, 3.145, 
    11.471, 12.183, 9.686, 12.562, 9.697, 3.34, 4.186, 4.485, 
    3.23, 4.229), Lipid.27 = c(5.848, 4.856, 6.503, 3.534, 5.358, 
    8.933, 14.034, 12.806, 7.781, 8.094, 6.765, 6.867, 5.539, 
    7.772, 5.883, 7.832, 8.607, 7.586, 6.628, 7.563), Lipid.28 = c(32.941, 
    30.579, 31.358, 15.861, 30.353, 25.222, 35.662, 34.035, 20.338, 
    24.682, 30.698, 34.024, 31.608, 37.539, 24.901, 20.131, 23.126, 
    30.803, 25.639, 18.935)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

clean up a the df:

```
# remove the columns which only contain NA:
data$Lipid.4 <- NULL
data$Lipid.7 <- NULL
data$Lipid.9 <- NULL

# convert from string to numeric (I do it now manually with each column. You could use a for-loop)
data$Lipid.10 <- gsub(",", ".", data$Lipid.10)  # convert comma to dot
data$Lipid.10 <- as.numeric(data$Lipid.10) # convert from string to numeric
data$Lipid.11 <- gsub(",", ".", data$Lipid.11)
data$Lipid.11 <- as.numeric(data$Lipid.11)
data$Lipid.17 <- gsub(",", ".", data$Lipid.17)
data$Lipid.17 <- as.numeric(data$Lipid.17)
```

```
# get the lipid column names
all_lipids <- colnames(data)
all_lipids <-  all_lipids[all_lipids != "ID"] # we don't need the ID column for the loop

# now loop over each column an perform a t-test
for (column in all_lipids) {
  print(column)
  print(t.test(data[,column] ~ data$ID))
}
```

You get for each lipid:

```
[1] "Lipid.1"

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  data[, column] by data$ID
t = 0.15843, df = 17.391, p-value = 0.8759
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2766112  0.3216112
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
         0.7144          0.6919
```

And just a final coment: you perform a lot of comparisons. You may consider to correct for multiple testing.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz ! I was thinking of using a for-loop too but I'm not entirely confident in my ability to do so, glad to see I wasn't too far off ^^ If I'm not wrong, we should be able to save the p-value of each iteration of the loop into a data frame too right ? And yeah, we're gonna adjust our p-value with a Bonferroni

Comment: The `for` loop is used very rarely in R. That's what many `map` functions are for. But I appreciate your simple notation of the `t.test` notation as `t.test(data[,column] ~ data$ID)`. In my case, it could have been written `t.test(data$val ~ data$ID)` which is certainly a more elegant and concise notation. Now we just have to wait for the solution to be accepted by the @Yo Pomdpin.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the data you pasted in is dirty! Instead of numbers, you have thongs. For example, `Lipid.10`

```
Lipid.10 = c("0,242", "0,254", "0,134", 
    "0,226", "0,243", "0,122", "0,082", "0,119", "0,098", "0,093", 
    "0,27", "0,284", "0,258", "0,236", "0,173", "0,106", "0,138", 
    "0,066", "0,072", "0,081")
```

Besides, you have variables that only contain NA values

```
Lipid.4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)
```

So I had to clean them up a bit.

```
structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    Lipid.1 = c(0.737, 0.419, 0.468, 0.805, 1.036, 0.825, 0.286, 
    1.166, 0.898, 0.504, 1.433, 0.41, 0.325, 0.866, 0.337, 0.876, 
    0.636, 0.953, 0.481, 0.602), Lipid.2 = c(0.001, 0.017, 0.013, 
    0.025, 0.018, 0.003, 0.007, NA, 0.01, 0.002, 0.01, 0.022, 
    0.005, NA, 0.018, NA, 0.015, 0.016, NA, 0.01), Lipid.3 = c(0.035, 
    0.018, 0.036, 0.024, 0.023, 0.027, 0.036, 0.037, 0.013, 0.037, 
    0.03, 0.04, 0.038, 0.033, 0.016, 0.034, 0.029, 0.033, 0.018, 
    0.029), Lipid.4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Lipid.5 = c(0.09, 
    0.099, 0.12, 0.058, 0.136, 0.103, 0.153, 0.148, 0.047, 0.085, 
    0.098, 0.133, 0.099, 0.121, 0.084, 0.065, 0.11, 0.088, 0.065, 
    0.043), Lipid.6 = c(0.39, 0.555, 0.568, 0.6, 0.626, 0.378, 
    0.657, 0.57, 0.271, 0.41, 0.474, 0.617, 0.491, 0.738, 0.459, 
    0.365, 0.499, 0.388, 0.271, 0.275), Lipid.7 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Lipid.8 = c(0.186, 0.197, 0.191, 0.125, 0.209, 
    0.107, 0.174, 0.143, 0.055, 0.134, 0.148, 0.193, 0.184, 0.213, 
    0.134, 0.085, 0.165, 0.215, 0.163, 0.061), Lipid.9 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.007), Lipid.10 = c(0.242, 0.254, 0.134, 0.226, 
    0.243, 0.122, 0.082, 0.119, 0.098, 0.093, 0.27, 0.284, 0.258, 
    0.236, 0.173, 0.106, 0.138, 0.066, 0.072, 0.081), Lipid.11 = c(0.053, 
    0.114, 0.038, 0.094, 0.073, 0.067, 0.028, 0.022, 0.021, 0.05, 
    0.085, 0.102, 0.122, 0.096, 0.027, 0.03, NA, 0.078, 0.066, 
    NA), Lipid.12 = c(0.223, 0.261, 0.258, 0.212, 0.168, 0.101, 
    0.191, 0.09, 0.195, 0.082, 0.155, 0.2, 0.167, 0.231, 0.145, 
    0.089, 0.239, 0.141, 0.106, 0.124), Lipid.13 = c(0.737, 0.763, 
    0.707, 0.587, 0.545, 0.317, 0.74, 0.602, 0.481, 0.531, 0.632, 
    0.448, 0.62, 0.766, 0.397, 0.623, 0.997, 0.578, 0.418, 0.412
    ), Lipid.14 = c(0.683, 0.666, 0.507, 0.366, 0.443, 0.266, 
    0.493, 0.345, 0.368, 0.355, 0.432, 0.411, 0.491, 0.565, 0.357, 
    0.285, 0.604, 0.426, 0.538, 0.295), Lipid.15 = c(0.911, 1.017, 
    0.503, 0.76, 0.741, 0.486, 0.648, 0.581, 0.955, 0.515, 0.932, 
    0.707, 0.626, 0.928, 0.836, 0.537, 0.654, 0.351, 0.498, 0.529
    ), Lipid.16 = c(0.148, 0.116, 0.069, 0.104, 0.091, 0.064, 
    0.093, 0.123, 0.11, 0.097, 0.283, 0.076, 0.095, 0.194, 0.06, 
    0.061, 0.086, 0.051, 0.064, 0.059), Lipid.17 = c(0.155, 0.274, 
    0.149, 0.127, 0.174, NA, 0.109, 0.134, 0.1, 0.09, 0.25, 0.112, 
    0.088, 0.243, 0.092, 0.073, 0.153, 0.12, 0.14, 0.06), Lipid.18 = c(3.143, 
    3.441, 4.359, 1.945, 2.573, 2.267, 3.585, 3.405, 2.296, 1.998, 
    3.468, 2.98, 3.626, 3.635, 3.236, 2.092, 2.586, 2.08, 1.718, 
    1.736), Lipid.19 = c(37.993, 36.148, 40.244, 30.395, 37.339, 
    35.742, 47.316, 47.555, 34.351, 32.377, 38.694, 39.413, 36.114, 
    41.235, 32.779, 32.222, 36.418, 36.918, 33.334, 31.421), 
    Lipid.20 = c(6.613, 5.913, 9.662, 3.789, 7.485, 6.297, 8.254, 
    8.07, 4.905, 5.686, 7.742, 7.533, 6.875, 7.908, 7.022, 5.446, 
    6.1, 6.782, 6.062, 6.089), Lipid.21 = c(7.235, 6.759, 8.331, 
    4.931, 6.558, 4.186, 5.99, 5.629, 3.066, 3.439, 7.102, 7.655, 
    6.606, 7.858, 5.804, 3.135, 3.218, 3.639, 2.975, 3.13), Lipid.22 = c(6.453, 
    6.664, 9.048, 4.341, 8.03, 7.599, 10.24, 10.954, 5.873, 6.687, 
    8.005, 8.908, 6.708, 8.06, 5.931, 6.083, 5.734, 5.587, 5.388, 
    6.088), Lipid.23 = c(4.943, 3.164, 5.153, 2.51, 4.071, 5.255, 
    7.636, 8.376, 4.726, 5.56, 4.762, 5.044, 4.549, 4.875, 4.57, 
    5.147, 4.396, 4.031, 3.556, 4.38), Lipid.24 = c(3.973, 4.279, 
    5.928, 3.066, 4.95, 4.667, 7.949, 7.268, 4.948, 3.72, 5.137, 
    5.539, 4.006, 5.276, 3.909, 4.163, 4.954, 5.02, 3.961, 4.201
    ), Lipid.25 = c(7.638, 5.224, 8.417, 3.902, 7.267, 6.007, 
    8.256, 7.457, 4.801, 4.86, 7.581, 8.173, 7.57, 8.591, 7.482, 
    5.091, 5.651, 6.577, 5.415, 5.76), Lipid.26 = c(10.225, 8.293, 
    13.188, 5.607, 10.993, 4.491, 5.767, 5.011, 3.589, 3.145, 
    11.471, 12.183, 9.686, 12.562, 9.697, 3.34, 4.186, 4.485, 
    3.23, 4.229), Lipid.27 = c(5.848, 4.856, 6.503, 3.534, 5.358, 
    8.933, 14.034, 12.806, 7.781, 8.094, 6.765, 6.867, 5.539, 
    7.772, 5.883, 7.832, 8.607, 7.586, 6.628, 7.563), Lipid.28 = c(32.941, 
    30.579, 31.358, 15.861, 30.353, 25.222, 35.662, 34.035, 20.338, 
    24.682, 30.698, 34.024, 31.608, 37.539, 24.901, 20.131, 23.126, 
    30.803, 25.639, 18.935)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The rest is easy.

```
library(tidyverse)

ft = function(data){
  tryCatch(
    {tout = t.test(data$val ~ data$ID))
    tibble(
      t = tout$statistic,
      p = tout$p.value,
      stderr = tout$stderr
    )
    }, error = function(msg){
      return(tibble(t = NA, p = NA, stderr = NA))
    })
}

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Lipid"), names_to = "Lipid", values_to = "val") %>% 
  group_by(Lipid) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(testt = map(data, ft)) %>% 
  select(Lipid, testt) %>% 
  unnest(testt)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 28 x 4
# Groups:   Lipid [28]
   Lipid         t      p   stderr
   <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Lipid.1   0.158  0.876  0.142  
 2 Lipid.2  -0.870  0.399  0.00350
 3 Lipid.3  -0.377  0.711  0.00372
 4 Lipid.4  NA     NA     NA      
 5 Lipid.5   0.930  0.366  0.0143 
 6 Lipid.6   0.730  0.475  0.0614 
 7 Lipid.7  NA     NA     NA      
 8 Lipid.8  -0.180  0.859  0.0223 
 9 Lipid.9  NA     NA     NA      
10 Lipid.10 -0.200  0.844  0.0355 
# ... with 18 more rows
```

Customize the `ft` function as needed.
I had to use the `tryCatch` function in `ft` because of variables that contain only `NA` values.

Comment: Thanks Marek ! Yeah I only saw afterward that the data weren't numeric, don't know why. Probably comes from higher-up (we got the data from anoter company). Lots of function I don't know in your script, I'm gonna look them up !

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Remember, however, that on Stack Overflow, you say thank you by selecting the approved solution.

Answer (score 0):

FYou can use the `multtest` library in `R` too, for multiple two-sample `t-tests`, as shown in the following code:

```
library(multtest)
df <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(dummy)))
X <- apply(as.matrix.noquote(df[2:nrow(df),]), 2, as.numeric) 
cl <- ifelse(df[1,] == 'A', 1, 0) # class labels
welch_t_stat <- mt.teststat(X, cl, test='t')
welch_t_stat
# [1]  0.15843467 -0.86954194 -0.37680666          NA  0.92978706  0.72969094          NA -0.17962582          NA          NA          NAv
# [12]  0.69705527  0.16001073  0.15733921  0.59540273 -0.05557413          NA  0.52706460  0.99860493 -0.14561137  0.58894166  1.25114061
# [23]  1.03458080  0.86540315 -0.62788116 -0.28806189  0.60206042  0.12954702
```

As can be seen from the above result, there are 28 Welch `t-tests` performed for 28 lipids in the dataframe.

Since you obtained individual `t-statistics`, now, you can compute the `p-values` and apply `FWER` corrections with Bonferroni / Holm or `FDR` corrections with Benjamini & Hochberg methods (useful when you have large number of tests):

```
raw_p <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(welch_t_stat))) # raw p-values assuming normal 
                                           # or use pt() with appropriate df
procedures <- c("Bonferroni", "Holm", "BH")
adjusted <- mt.rawp2adjp(raw_p, procedures)
```